# Why does OpenSSL not return the same values using public_key.verify and private_key.private_encrypt(digest)

Tags: ruby, openssl, cryptography, signature

As far as I understand, signing data with an asymmetric key pair is essentially the same as using the private key to encrypt that same data. It says as much here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html. Ruby openssl seems to use an approach of hashing the data first then signing it. So I am confused why the value of signature is not equivalent at the end of both operations:

1.

```
data = 'Sign me!'
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)
signature = pkey.sign(digest, data)
puts signature
```

2.

```
data = 'Sign me!'
data_hash = OpenSSL::Digest::digest("SHA256", data)
signature = pkey.private_encrypt(data_hash.to_s)
puts signature
```

(or if the digest is not working as I thought)

3.

```
data = 'Sign me!'
signature = pkey.private_encrypt(data)
puts signature
```

I am guessing that there are formatting things going on in the background. Now, this is for academic understanding, I will use verify for actual signature verification.

Comment: This is not specific to Ruby, maybe you can find your answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172) on the crypto site. I created this Q/A mainly because many questions like these on StackOverflow.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I think it does answer it. Do you also? Please confirm, and I will delete this question. Thanks. That was actually the question I was going to ask and couldn't find (I don't know why).

Comment: Yes, I do think that.

Comment: I had a hard time finding this information incidently. I think it may be good to have here. I would like you give you the opportunity to offer an answer based on your other question, or I will create my own when I have a chance.